# Why ScrollView with ScrollViewReader does not scroll with animation

Tags: swift, swiftui, scrollview, scrollviewreader

I am using ScrollViewReader to slowly scroll images behind text. On my ScrollView I am using:

```
.onAppear {
                        withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                            proxy.scrollTo(9, anchor: .bottom)
                        }
                    }
```

But it scrolling immediately and without animation. What am I doing wrong?

I am not attaching images, but they all have .id, so that's not a problem.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] - this snippet is not enough

Comment: This answer might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62535553/swiftui-customize-animation-for-scrollto-using-scrollviewreader