Animation is not working as expected when programatilcly scrolling to in SwiftUI
I have a ScrollReader that wraps a ScrollView, this scrollView has an onChange modifier, so my problem is that when I try to use value.scrollTo(...) with withAnimation the type of animation, duration, and delay I am setting is not working at all, it looks like it playing .default all the time
I tried to use timers, DispatchQueue - no result
Here is my small scroll to code:
withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 2).delay(2.5)) { // type, duration and delay are not working
                            value.scrollTo("text", anchor: .bottom)
                        }

If you have any questions, you are welcome

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62535553/swiftui-customize-animation-for-scrollto-using-scrollviewreader
I think here is the same question

already checked, not working for me

withAnimation() is used to animate a state-change ("the result of recomputing the view’s body). scrollTo is a programatic call. they are not compatible - and afaik you cannot change the animation of the ScrollReader API.
